# How read response from a post request in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, node.js

I have written a method which sending an mail to my client in node.js like this :-

```
app.post('/sendemail',(req, res) => {
  const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  ;
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({service: 'gmail ',

auth: {
user: 'atul.11192@gmail.com',
pass: 'xxxxxxx'
},
    tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false
}
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
      from: '"Enquiry from datadock" <atul.11192@gmail.com>', // sender address
      to: 'atul.11192@gmail.com', // list of receivers
      subject: 'Datadock Enquiry ', // Subject line
      text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
      html: output // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          res.send('error');
      }
        res.redirect('home.ejs',{message:"message sent"});
  });
  });
```

now i want to write an jquery function to read the response which i have sent from this method and show a modal , how can i write this code ? i have to use j query as using javascript is not possible due to many routes

Answer (score 1):

Because you are redirecting to a new router you will need to set the data you want to send to the frontend in a session. You can avoid this however by sending a response to the same router. To achieve this:

```
jQuery('button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/sendemail',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.message);
            jQuery('.yourModal').text(data.message).show();
            /*setTimeout(function() {
            //window.location.href = data.yourRedirectUrl;
            }, 1000);*/
        }
    });
});
```

Then you'll need to replace the below:

```
res.redirect('home.ejs',{message:"message sent"})
```

With this:

```
res.end(JSON.stringify({message:"message sent", yourRedirectUrl: '/home'});
```

If you still need to redirect, you can uncomment the `setTimeout` function I've added in the ajax script.

Edit: Alternatively you could just set your redirect to have a hash

```
res.redirect('home#mailsent',{message:"message sent"})
```

And put the following on home.ejs:

```
jQuery(document).on(‘load’, function(){
    if(window.location.hash == ‘mailsent’) {
        // Do stuff with your modal here
    }
});
```

Comment: do i need to make it an on button click event or it will work individually without on click button event ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. For the first solution, yes. For the alternative solution of adding a hash, no. I'd recommend using the alternative personally and just adding a hash onto the end of the url you want to redirect the user to. That way when they land on the home page with that hash you can show your modal.